# is there a settings app in Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

i'm looking into doing a settings page in my app, 
and i'm trying to recreate this screens

[image]

[image]

is there any specific view to achieve that in xcode ? (similar to the settings activity in android) ? 
what would be the best approach in doing a page like that ?

Answer (score 0):

found it
with the help of this tutorial
https://shrikar.com/xcode-6-tutorial-grouped-uitableview/